# In Chef, how to load many attributes for use in templates?

Tags: json, templates, chef-infra

I have a recipe that needs to process several templates. Together these templates have over 100 variables that need to be populated. I have the values that need to be injected into the templates currently stored in JSON files.

I can use the JSON gem in a ruby_block to parse the files, but how to get that new data into the templates?

Answer (score 0):

You can access any variables that you define in that block in the templates. If it's a JSON file, you might turn that into a dictionary (e.g. name it `json_i_just_read`) in a block and then make a template block inside that. In the template you would just use ERB:

```
config_opt1 = <%= json_i_just_read['value1'] %>
```